# mysql dumps from linux terminal in seperate files for each table

Tags: mysql, linux

**I am trying to take backups of the tables in a Database from linux terminal. I am using the following script to do it**

```
GIT_MYSQL=/data/database/location to store
for T in `mysql -u [user] -h [Hostname] -p [database] -N -B -e 'show tables from database_name'`;
do
    echo "Backing up $T"
    mysqldump --skip-comments --compact -u [user] -p [password] [database] $T > $GIT_MYSQL/$T.sql
done;
```

**I get the following error:**
mysqldump: Got error: 2002: Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' (2) when trying to connect
My mysql.sock is not present in the folder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need the `-h [Hostname]` option to `mysqldump`, otherwise it will try to dump from a local database rather than the remote server that you got the list of tables from.

And to provide a password on the command line rather than prompting for it, you need to use `--password=[password]` or `-p[password]`; you can't have a space before the password.

```
mysqldump --skip-comments --compact -u [user] -h [Hostname] -p'[password]' [database] $T > $GIT_MYSQL/$T.sql
```

Comment: Thank you it worked. Also,is there a way to backup the stored procedures and functions in a similar way?

Comment: See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysqldump-stored-programs.html

Comment: How can I get them is seperate files. Is there a command like 'Show tables from database' to show names of stores procedures and function so I can loop over it.

Comment: I need it for procedures and functions. Table is done.

Comment: What would you do with the list of procedure names? The option to dump procedures doesn't let you specify a procedure name, it dumps all of them.